# Move a node into another node in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

## Need to move the document/body/tbl/tr/tc/tbl and its content to document/body/tbl. should be placed after the parent tbl. I was able to move the inner tbl but it moved after the last outer tbl.

```
<document>
<body>
    <p>text1</p>
    <tbl>
        <tblPr>tablePR</tblPr>
        <tblGrid>tableGrid</tblGrid>
        <tr rsidR="00A13445">
            <tblPrEx>tablePrex</tblPrEx>
            <tc>
                <tcPr>TCPR</tcPr>
                <p>text2</p>
                <tbl>
                    <tblPr>table2PR</tblPr>
                    <tblGrid>table2Grid</tblGrid>
                    <tr>table2TR</tr>
                </tbl>
            </tc>
        </tr>
    </tbl>
    <p>text3</p>
    <p>text3</p>
    <p>text3</p>
    <tbl>
        <tblPr>table3PR</tblPr>
        <tblGrid>table3Grid</tblGrid>
        <tr rsidR="00A13445">
            <tblPrEx>table3Prex</tblPrEx>
            <tc>
                <tcPr>TCPR</tcPr>
                <p>text4</p>
                <tbl>
                    <tblPr>table4Pr</tblPr>
                    <tblGrid>table4Grid</tblGrid>
                    <tr>table4Grid</tr>
                </tbl>
            </tc>
        </tr>
    </tbl>
</body>
```

## expected output must be:

```
<document>
<body>
    <p>text1</p>
    <tbl>
        <tblPr>tablePR</tblPr>
        <tblGrid>tableGrid</tblGrid>
        <tr rsidR="00A13445">
            <tblPrEx>tablePrex</tblPrEx>
            <tc>
                <tcPr>TCPR</tcPr>
                <p>text2</p>
            </tc>
        </tr>
    </tbl>
    <tbl>
        <tblPr>table2PR</tblPr>
        <tblGrid>table2Grid</tblGrid>
        <tr>table2TR</tr>
    </tbl>
    <p>text3</p>
    <p>text3</p>
    <p>text3</p>
    <tbl>
        <tblPr>table3PR</tblPr>
        <tblGrid>table3Grid</tblGrid>
        <tr rsidR="00A13445">
            <tblPrEx>table3Prex</tblPrEx>
            <tc>
                <tcPr>TCPR</tcPr>
                <p>text4</p>
            </tc>
        </tr>
    </tbl>
    <tbl>
        <tblPr>table4Pr</tblPr>
        <tblGrid>table4Grid</tblGrid>
        <tr>table4Grid</tr>
    </tbl>
</body>
```